# Append jquery textarea ckeditor not working

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor, append

When I put the html tags ckeditor outside activities
but when I put ckeditor in jquery append then it does not work

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <a class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</a>
    <div></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-3">Project</label><div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12"><select class="bs-select form-control" name="project"><option value="" >------------- Select project -----------</option>@forelse($parent as $item)<option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->title}}</option>@empty @endforelse</select></div></div><textarea  class="form-control" id="editor1" name="content_vi[]" rows="6" required></textarea><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use "insertHtml" or "insertText" function for appending data into the CKEDITOR. Like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['input-text-area-ID'].insertHtml(data);
```

> If you want to remove previous data and add new one use "setData" function. Like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['input-text-area-ID'].setData(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have these 2 varibales

```
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
var add_button= $(".add_field_button");
```

then you are using them like

```
$(wrapper).apend();
```

it means

```
$($(".input_fields_wrap")).append();
```

which is wrong either use it like
wrapper.append();
or change var wrapper like

```
var wrapper = ".input_field_wrap";
```

same thing you are doing with the add_button
and its always better to you

```
$().on('click',function(){
});
```

then

```
$().click(function(){
});
```